# Grammar transformation for recursive descent

Tags: recursion

I am trying to transform a given grammar in order to be ready for recursive descent. The rules I end up are:

```
SEQ --> constSEQ | operZ     
Z --> exprX | operX   
Y --> exprX | operX   
X --> expr | exproperX | ε  .
```

What am I supposed to do with Z and Y that are the same?

Is any of them eliminated?

Answer (score 0):

A bit hard to say without knowing the software system used (and its intelligence).

If on the left hand side all non-terminals must be unique (no or'ed rules `Y --> exprX` and `Y --> operX`), then the only purpose would be metainformation, maybe for a different semantic interpretation of a generated AST.

But yes, a fine possibility to loop reducing the grammar. On the other hand a produced function Y could just call Z.

(Mind `exprX | operX` might be the same as `operX | exprX` depending on the specific grammar's symbols or the type like `LL(1)`.)

Also `A --> X B` and `B -> X A` are redundant.

One would need to loop over the rules till no reduction possible.

```
boolean checkRulesAreTheSame(Rule rule1, Rule rule2, Context context) {
    context.setNonTerminalsTheSame(true, rule1.nonTerminal, rule2.nonTerminal);
    if (productionsTheSame(rule1.production, rule2.production, context)) {
        return true;
    }
    context.setNonTerminalsTheSame(false, rule1.nonTerminal, rule2.nonTerminal);
    return false;
}
```

The rarer case `A --> X B` and `B -> X C` and `C -> X A` would not be found by this comparison of just 2 non-terminals.